# Python class in function that use function params throw NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python

When I define a class in function that use function's params, throw NameError: name 'x' is not defined.

```
def foo(x):
  class Meta:
    x = x

foo(1)

# throw NameError
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field `x` inside the class is masking the parameter `x` from the function.

```
def foo(x):
  class Meta:
    y = x

foo(1)
```

will stop giving you this error.

The question is poorly written (there is not even a question), so I might have misunderstood you.

Comment: Sorry, my english very poor.... and thank you very much to answer my question~